# NodeJS + Socket.IO : Problem accessing room variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am new to the technologies NodeJS and Socket.io and i am facing a problem with the variables stored in io.sockets.adapter.rooms.

I have my app.js :

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('message', function (room) {
      socket.join(room);
      console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
      io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room].variable = "This is a test";
  })
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <input type="button" value="Press me" id="test">
<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function () {
            socket.emit('message', 'room1');
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the server return this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'variable' of undefined
```

It means that "io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room].variable" is undefined but i do not understant how i can define it otherwise.

By the way I am using NodeJS 12.8.3 and express 4.17.1

Maybe I need a specific module ?

Thanks a lot to everyone who will take the time to answer this

Comment: In some versions of socket.io (2.x and earlier) and in some configurations, `socket.join()` is asynchronous and will not complete until some time later when the optional callback that you can pass it is called.  So, you may be attempting to access the room before it has been created.  I think the absolute latest version of socket.io (version 3.x) has actually made `socket.join()` synchronous so it would complete immediately and your code could work.

Comment: I have the 3.0.3 version of socket.io, and it is not working, maybe it needs another module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their changelog for [v3.0.0](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/releases/tag/3.0.0) they mention the following
*Socket#rooms is now a Set instead of an object*

Which means it's now a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of a [normal js object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

So with v3.0.3 you get the following output when logging the rooms, which you can't access by key like a normal js object, and .set() has to be used instead.

```
Map(2) {
  'II-OqYrpZYtv2bKrAAAD' => Set(1) { 'II-OqYrpZYtv2bKrAAAD' },
  'room1' => Set(1) { 'II-OqYrpZYtv2bKrAAAD' }
}
```

Although I have no idea how to add an additional variable to the room. Since if you run the following code:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.set(room, {
  variable: "Test variable"
})
```

it replaces the socket id with the new variable. I can't find anything on how they want us to store variables using this new structure.

```
Map(2) {
  'Xv6vbxuOgDuqp6dmAAAB' => Set(1) { 'Xv6vbxuOgDuqp6dmAAAB' },
  'room1' => { variable: 'Test variable' }
}
```

When logging the rooms with v2.0.3 you get a normal object output which you can access with [key].

```
{
  'tVnQpZyKDglSf4J-AAAA': Room { sockets: { 'tVnQpZyKDglSf4J-AAAA': true }, length: 1 },
  room1: Room { sockets: { 'tVnQpZyKDglSf4J-AAAA': true }, length: 1 }
}
```

So if you revert socket.io back to v2.0.3 (the latest 2.x.x version) your code works fine.

You can revert socket.io by running the following

```
npm i socket.io@2.0.3
```

Or by changing the version number in package.json and then running

```
npm install
```